# How to wait untill Observable Observer is created

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to build messaging system with Observable. My code look like this, pretty simple.
But I has slide problem, sometimes method **newMessage** calls before **storageObserver** is created, and I'm getting this error

> Cannot read property 'next' of null

```
  private storageObserver: any;
  public storage: any;

  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService, private http: HttpClient) 
  {
    this.storage = Observable.create(observer => {
      this.storageObserver = observer;
    });
  }

  newMessage(message: any) {
    this.storageObserver.next(message);
  }
```

Obviously I can check in **newMessage** like this

```
newMessage(message: any) {
    if(this.storageObserver == null) {
      setTimeout(() => {
         this.storageObserver.next(message);
      }, 500)
    } else {
      this.storageObserver.next(message);
    }
}
```

But I don't really like this type of hacks. Is any proper way to wait till observer is created?

Comment: Instead of Observable you can use a Subject in this case, anyway you can define the observable outside the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want to be able to 'feed' the observable manually, for as long as you want, but there is another approach to do that.

I prefer to write it like this:

```
private storageSubject: Subject<any>;

constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.storageSubject = new Subject<any>();
    this.storage$ = this.storageSubject.asObservable(); 
}

// This is a public observable that can be subscribed to.
// Do not forget to unsubscribe.
storage$: Observable<any>;

newMessage(message: any) {
    this.storageSubject.next(message);
}
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lvuba5)

Note: If you want the observable to have an initial value, you can use `BehaviorSubject<any>`. It will always give the last value immediately after subscribtion, which can be more useful if you want the value to have some form of state.